# Pushback buffer overflow - but my buffer isn't full yet?

Tags: java, buffer-overflow

I'm implementing a syntax reader as a spin-off from a homework assignment, and I'm reading an XML file one character at a time. My goal is to take the code that I passed the lab assignment with, and improve the structure and design.

I have a `SyntaxReader` that inherits from `PushbackReader`, which has some extra methods like `readAndExpect(char c)`, `trimWhitespace()` and `readUntilChar(char c)`. Then I have an `XMLSyntaxReader` that inherits from `SyntaxReader` and adds functionality like `readAttribute()` and `readNode()` (the latter being recursive for children in the tree...).

I have basically just taken the working code from my lab assignment and pasted it into the appropriate places in this approach. However, when I try to read the first child, I'm getting an `IOException: Pushback buffer overflow` that I can't figure out.

This is the beginning of my XML file:

```
<Biosfar namn="Liv">ar allt som fortplantar sig
    <Rike namn="Vaxter"> etc...
```

I have debugged and watched the syntax readers successfully read all the way through `<R` at the beginning of the child tag. At that point, the `XMLSyntaxReader` confirms that it is a child tag, unreads the two last characters (`R` and `<`, in that order) and calls on `readNode()` to parse the child node. The exception occurs when I try to unread `<`.

In the debugger, I have also verified that the private `pos` variable of the `PushbackReader` is really set to `0`, but I can't figure out why. I've parsed a full line of text - why don't those characters still count?

*I'd post my code, but it's quite lengthy and as the same worked before I'm not sure my exact implementation is relevant. If it is, please point to someplace I can upload snippets, and I'll share all the code.*

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without seeing some code. Please make sure that you actually use the constructor specifying the correct buffer size (the default is 1).

Comment: @Jörn: If I had included only parts of my code, the constructor probably hadn't been in there anyway since I didn't think it was relevant (I had no idea of the buffer size - I thought it was the entire stream...), so it would only have been there if I had shown my *entire* code, which I deemed too lenghty. And as both you and Adrian Mouat suggested, the problem was with the buffer size and could be found and solved without seeing my actual code =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't the default size of the [PushbackReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html) buffer only 1? That would cause this problem when you push the second character. What happens if you increase the size of the buffer?

Comment: Good catch! Increasing the size of the buffer to 2 solved the problem! =) For luck-seekers finding this question in the future: the buffer size has no setter, so it has to be set using the constructor `PushbackReader(Reader in, int size)`.

Answer (score 1):

I got with it this:

```
byte[] bytes = programaFonte.getBytes();

PushbackReader reader = new PushbackReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)),bytes.length);
```

Comment: That way you're defaulting to worst-case memory usage, though - you're effectively saying that you might want to read the entire stream, then push the entire thing back onto the reader again. In my use case, I would only ever need to push back 2 characters, so there's no need to allocate a larger buffer than that. I don't know what your use case is, but if you might need to push back the entire stream, you're probably better off reading the entire thing into a `String` in the first place, and then working with that instead.